# Wix Setup Project for Windows Service causes FileNotFoundException

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, installation

I have created a Wix Setup Project for a Windows Service. On my local developer machine (Windows 7 - 64) it runs and starts without problems. However when I try to install it on a Windows Server 2008 I get the "common" error of "Verify you have sufficient priviliges...". In the Event Viewer I can see that this is caused by the .NET Runtime throws a FileNotFoundException

> Application: RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> Stack:    at RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.Program.Main()

I've tried added all the files I could think of in my .wxs-file. It is as following

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="AutoBettingWinService.Setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Norsk RT" UpgradeCode="5756e8b0-3eef-4b1c-9c74-60c05386bff5">

        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="AutoBettingWinService.Setup" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AutoBettingWinService.Setup" >
        </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService" Guid="{8B3B5B09-701E-4BA4-9FD2-093072B303D3}">
        <File Id="Common.Logging.dll" Name="Common.Logging.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\Common.Logging.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="RT.Tools.Betting.dll" Name="RT.Tools.Betting.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\RT.Tools.Betting.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="Moq.dll" Name="Moq.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\Moq.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="nunit.framework.dll" Name="nunit.framework.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="Quartz.dll" Name="Quartz.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\Quartz.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="RT.Testing.dll" Name="RT.Testing.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\RT.Testing.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="RT.WebAPI.dll" Name="RT.WebAPI.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\RT.WebAPI.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="System.Net.Http.dll" Name="System.Net.Http.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" Name="System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" Name="System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="System.Web.Http.dll" Name="System.Web.Http.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\System.Web.Http.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" Name="System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="Thinktecture.IdentityModel.dll" Name="Thinktecture.IdentityModel.dll" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\Thinktecture.IdentityModel.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>

        <File Id="_1000UserIds.txt" Name="1000UserIds.txt" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\1000UserIds.txt" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>

        <File Id="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe.manifest" Name="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe.manifest" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe.manifest" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe.config" Name="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe.config" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe.config" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>

        <File Id="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.pdb" Name="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.pdb" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.pdb" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
        <File Id="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe" Name="RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe" Source="..\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService\bin\Debug\RT.Tools.AutoBettingWinService.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/>
        <ServiceInstall
              Id="ServiceInstaller"
              Type="ownProcess"
              Vital="yes"
              Name="AutoBettingService"
              DisplayName="AutoBettingService"
              Description="Places bets automatically a given time of day"
              Start="auto"
              Account="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
              ErrorControl="normal"
              Interactive="no"
              >
        </ServiceInstall>
        <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="AutoBettingService" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I've also tried to omit the 'Start' property and tried to start it manually, with the same result.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my setup? And why the FileNotFoundException?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what @Christopher Painter has said, I am going to assume that the problem is not with the install but rather what is *not* being installed, you have already alluded to not being sure what is dependencies your service has, so you should start diagnosing what dependencies your application requires.

Install the application but do not start the service, then start the service manually and by using [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this will allow you to view binding failures at runtime, you may have to set `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\ForceLog` to 1 to get all failures (see link for more details).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to profile the service to find out what is referred to by the FileNotFound exception and add it to the installer.  Also, Windows Installer Component rules dictate that every one of your DLL files needs to be the keyfile of it's own component.

Comment: BTW, be sure to understand the working directory for a service is System32.  If you are looking for %CD%\1000UserIds.txt it won't be found.  You'll have to determine the directory of the executing assembly and then look for it in that folder.